# Which algorithm applies for the current number of daily up/down votes left actually?

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes, rate-limiting

Am I the only one experiencing the variability in the

> You have *<X>* number of votes left today.

message?

I can't really get the pattern, why I sometimes seem to gain more votes left, based on my recent activity.

Is this algo completely undisclosed, or can someone shed some light on how this actually works?

---

For samples, I've been able to [downvote this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206214/trying-to-create-a-checkerboard-with-variable-size), ***after I was getting a note***, that I'm out of up-/down votes today with stating a certain time period, and that didn't have been elapsed at that point of time.

Comment: If nobody blames caching I would go for posts that got deleted after you voted.

Comment: The Overmeta knows all, as always :) See [Separate vote pools for questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers) and [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes).

Comment: @rene Yeah, I don't really get the relation on probably deleted posts. But there's no evidence this really applied.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No the behavior is different. I'm not getting more vote casts left, depending on questions or answers. These seemingly vary with my current behavior within the _daily_ timing limit.

Comment: @πάντα, fair enough. Let's blame caching :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Hmm, may be I have to observe the behavior more thoroughly, could well be it's about that extra votes for questions. Though I'm less (down) voting on answers, therefore still wondering a bit. Is it we effectively have 40 up-/downvotes available a day for judgeing questions, or is there some more subtle algorithm working?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i did a little more research and it looks like the implementation changed and wasn't really advertised heavily.  It is a little odd, but it might explain what you are seeing.  I am writing an answer to explain why I found.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no secret to the algorithm on voting, although it is no longer as simple as 30 votes, and 10 extra votes for questions only as I previously thought.

The actual answer is in [waffles answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/182513) to [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)

> New behavior:
>
> - Everyone gets a total of 30 votes.
> - You may get up to 10 extra question votes.
> - Warnings remain simple... (5 votes remaining, 4 votes remaining...)
> - Question votes may be cast at any time during the day. However, once you reach the N votes remaining warnings, stuff is set in stone. A question voting spree at the end will still count down.

The way I interpret this is you still get 30 votes to use as you see fit, but rather than forcing users to go on a question voting spree at the end of the day like the old implementation required, you can start using your question-only votes before you run out of votes.  If you use all of your question votes before you vote on 30 answers, you will still get all of your question only votes. But if you vote on fewer than 10 questions before you vote on 30 total posts, you will lose *some* of you 10 extra question votes.

The last bullet is a little fuzzy (and if you read the comments on the answer, others are confused by it), so I can't confirm **exactly** how the countdown works, but it should be based on how many questions you vote on during the day.